# Updating existing rows Postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a table of api calls grouped by hour, then by user, then by api key.  I have many of these from different hosts, in pandas dataframes, and am wondering how to do the following. 
My rows look like:

`timestamp userid apikey 2xx-count 4xx-count 5xx-count`

The issue I am having is with writing the sql.  I can have two dataframes with calls from the same api key during the same hour, and want to sum them in the database.  Here is some pseudocode for what I am trying to do:

```
merge newrow into table on timestamp, userid, apikey:
    2xx-count = oldrow.2xx-count + newrow.2xx-count
    4xx-count = oldrow.4xx-count + newrow.4xx-count
    5xx-count = oldrow.5xx-count + newrow.5xx-count
```

How would I go about doing this in postgresql/python